# How to handle config for Rails Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am working on releasing my first Gem for Rails. It is pretty simple, but I am needing to provide some access to setting config options. I'd like to have the user put something in 'config/initializers' and tie into that with my gem.

So, the question is: Is there a best-practice for providing config options in a Rails gem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In an engine I help develop, [Forem](https://github.com/radar/forem), we use `mattr_accessors` on the top-level constant like this:

**lib/forem.rb**

```
module Forem
  mattr_accessor :user_class, :theme, :formatter, :default_gravatar, :default_gravatar_image,
                 :user_profile_links, :email_from_address, :autocomplete_field,
                 :avatar_user_method, :per_page
...
```

Then inside `config/initializers` we ask users to set them up like this:

```
Forem.user_class = 'User'
Forem.autocomplete_field = :login
```

With a short gem name, there's not much difference between this solution and the other one I will propose.

---

**Solution #2**

Still use `mattr_accessors` on your top-level constant but offer a `config` method on this module that takes a block and yields the object:

```
module ReallyComplicatedGemName
  mattr_accessor :....
  def self.config(&block)
    yield(self)
  end
...
```

This way people can do:

```
ReallyComplicatedGemName.config do |config|
  config.user_class = "User"
  ...
end
```